# camera not found - How to find the right driver for asus ROG gl552vw

Tags: drivers, webcam

After a windows update, my camera broke (camera not found error). I've found things talked about online about this but nothing that leads me to the holy grain.

On their driver download page, I find drivers to download but nothing which specifically references the webcam. Ergo, I don't know what to fix.

I don't know the name of my camera or how to get it, so I can't google it.

In device manager, I looked under the HID section and the Other Devices section. There is no imaging device section so I was going to install that manually but my brand was not listed.

I am at a loss. I would try rollback my driver if I could figure out which one to do. Many of the drivers don't have the option of rolling back and they show the date as being in 2006.

Not sure what to do. Kind of at a loss, which is frustrating because I feel I've already gotten pretty deep into this. I like how problems can teach you new things, but why on their website doesn't it say a driver for a camera? Does it fall under some larger category? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched Asus's website for the driver? If there are multiple options, try each one.

Comment: Of course search by the laptop model number. Don't just try every one on their site.

Comment: It's likely the camera uses a generic Windows driver and if so, you won't find it.

Comment: I searched their website by the model number. I think GabrielaGarcia is onto something. So how would I find it if it's generic?

Comment: Well, if it is and it suddenly disappeared after an Windows Update there's nothing you can do except maybe rollback the update or  use some restore point prior to that update.

Comment: Run the hardware troubleshooter to check if that helps. If not, install [YouCam 8 Essential](https://www.cyberlink.com/downloads/trials/youcam/download_en_US.html) and see if finds the camera.

Comment: You don't even provide your OS version. How are we supposed to help you?